# How to adjust the FrameTicks length in DateListPlot?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

Suppose I have the data for `DateListPlot`:

```
dates = DateList[{2002, 1, 2 #}] & /@ Range@600;
values = Accumulate@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 600];

DateListPlot[Transpose@{dates, values}, Joined -> True, 
FrameTicks -> {{{#, #, {0, 0.05}} & /@ Range[-30, 30, 2], 
None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

gives

[image]

But I want the longer `FrameTicks` for x-axes(same length as y-axes),so I try:

```
DateListPlot[Transpose@{dates, values}, Joined -> True, 
FrameTicks -> {{{#, #, {0, 0.05}} & /@ Range[-30, 30, 2], 
None}, {{#, #, {0, 0.05}} & /@ Range[2002, 2012, 1], None}}]
```

[image]

Errr~~~x-axes has gone~~What should I do?

Comment: The code would work, if the ticks for the x-axes wouldn't require a date format (e.g., like it's the case for `ListPlot`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just one pair of `{}` missing

```
DateListPlot[Transpose@{dates, values}, Joined -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{#, #, {0, 0.05}} & /@ Range[-30, 30, 2], None}, 
  {{{#}, #, {0, 0.05}} & /@ Range[2002, 2012, 1], None}}]
```

> [image]

By adding the extra `{}` a shortened date list is created, which is one of the possible date forms needed for the x-axis. Other possible forms are listed in the *Details and Options* section of [`DateListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html?q=DateListPlot).

Answer (score 1):

```
dateTicksF[n_: 5, tl_: {0, .05}, style_: Thin] := Module[{ticks = 
 Graphics`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{#, #2}, n, 
   Graphics`DateListPlotDump`TickLength -> tl, Charting`TickStyle -> style]}, 
 Join[ticks, {{ticks[[2, 1]], "", 1.5 tl, Opacity[0] }}]] &
```

**Examples:**

```
dates = DateList[{2002, 1, 15 #}] & /@ Range@600;
values = Accumulate@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 600];

DateListPlot[Transpose@{dates, values}, Joined -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{#, #, {0, 0.05}} & /@ Range[-30, 30, 2], 
    None}, {dateTicksF[], None}}]
```

[image]

Use `dateTicksF[10, {.03, .03}, Red]` in place of `dateTicksF[]` to get

[image]